# Rails how to force download on chrome ios

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller action like below. The idea is to force download instead of viewing on the browser. It works pretty well on desktop both chrome, firefox and ie. However, it doesn't work on chrome mobile ios at all. By the way, the file is very small, so I did via `#send_data`.

```
def download
  @attachment = current_listing.attachments.find(params[:id].to_i)

  url  = URI.escape(@attachment.url)
  data = open(url).read

  send_data data, type: 'application/octet-stream', disposition: 'attachment', filename: @attachment.file_name
end
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the official Rails 4 documentation for [ActionController::DataStream.send_data](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)

the only available values for the disposition key are: 'attachment' and 'inline' with attachment as it's default.

Also the application/octet-stream is set by default.

The command:

```
send_data data, filename: @attachment.file_name
```

Should suffice

Comment: Thanks, it was my typo. I already set it to 'attachment', but it still doesn't work on chrome mobile.